# Missing required parameters for [Route: bricks.update] [URI: bricks/{brick}]. (View: /home/Development/ad-et/resources/views/bricks/edit.blade.php)

Tags: laravel, laravel-7

***I'm using Laravel 7 and got stuck since few days!***

**Controller:**

```
public function edit(Bricks $bricks)
{
    return view('bricks.edit', compact('bricks'));
}
```

**Routes:**

```
Route::resource('bricks','BricksController');
```

**Index:**

```
<a href="{{ route('bricks.edit',$item->id) }}" class="btn btn-sm btn-warning btn-circle">
      EDIT
</a>
```

**edit blade file:**

```
       <form action="{{ route('bricks.update',$bricks->id) }}" method="POST">
        @csrf
        @method('PUT')
          <div class="box-body">
            <div class="form-group">
              <label for="">Vehicle Number</label>
              <input name="vehicle_number" value="{{ $bricks->vehicle_number }}" type="name" class="form-control" id="" placeholder="Enter Vehicle Number">
            </div>
            <div class="form-group">
              <label for="">Bill Number</label>
              <input name="bill_number" value="{{ $bricks->bill_number }}" type="name" class="form-control" id="" placeholder="Enter Bill Number">
            </div>
            <div class="form-group">
              <label for="">Per Unit Rate</label>
              <input name="per_unit_rate" value="{{ $bricks->per_unit_rate }}" type="number" class="form-control" id="" placeholder="Enter Per Unit Rate">
            </div>
            <div class="form-group">
              <label for="">Total Units</label>
              <input name="total_units" value="{{ $bricks->total_units }}" type="number" class="form-control" id="" placeholder="Enter Total Units">
            </div>
            <div class="form-group">
              <label for="">Total Rate</label>
              <input name="total_rate" value="{{ $bricks->total_rate }}" type="number" class="form-control" id="" placeholder="Enter Total Rate">
            </div>
          </div>
          <!-- /.box-body -->
          <div class="box-footer">
            <button type="submit" class="btn btn-primary">Update This Entry</button>
          </div>
        </form>
```

I just added the edit.blade.php file in which the error is occuring!

Comment: Your question is about  `bricks.update`,  post related blade code

Comment: just added the edit.blade file above

Comment: Try this `{{ route('bricks.update', ['brick' => $bricks->id]) }}`

Comment: it did'nt helped

Comment: Do you get this error on edit page after hitting the submit button of the form?

Comment: On visiting the edit page

Comment: Is your model variable $bricks or $brick when loading the view? I think you need to change the $bricks to $brick everywhere in the view file.

Comment: @Shoaib, then you must have put an <a> tag or something and used route ('bricks.update') there without it's parameter. That's why you don't get to access the edit page.   The error should also depict the exact line that is throwing the error.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
public function edit(Bricks $brick)
{
    return view('bricks.edit', compact('brick'));
}
```

and change the variable in the view file too.

Comment: Great, it worked. i just need to change the variables to singular! Also is'nt there any method to keep the variables to plural?

Comment: there is a method, but you are editing 1 brick, so using singular would be the right way to go

Comment: I wonder why would it matter do use singular or plural names :)

Comment: @AhmadKarimi because I wrote that part of the resource registrar to use singular names for resources (for the route parameters), you can have it not do that conversion to singular for all resources or a single resource if you wish ... the name matters because that is Implicit Route Model Binding happening

Comment: @lagbox you wrote that part?  :-D I was trying to comment to why they should use a singular name for a singular object... but i never came up with a polite way of making that clear

Comment: the reason for a singular name is in your controller method you will be referring to a 'singular' item ... "Edit this user", you wouldn't say "Edit this users" ... so the variable for something that holds one of something is singular ... the resource collection (root) could be plural but a single resource is singular .... `users/{user}` .... its just way to have some standard that most people preferred, but you don't have to follow this and it can be overridden

Comment: @GertB. yes, a long time ago  https://github.com/laravel/framework/commit/38032b2b46cdff6eb751006f245d52671e662e2d  https://github.com/laravel/framework/commit/44f1bc5a24f749bb6d27e022d190fcc13a654834